# Convert flat object to hierarchy with c#

Tags: c#, linq, data-structures

I've seen similar questions but not something which answers my scenario.  So...

Given the types:

```
public class Flat
{
    public string Group1 { get; set; }
    public string Group2 { get; set; }  
    public int Value { get; set; }
}

public class Group1 
{
    public Name { get; set; }
    public Group2[] Group2 { get; set; }
}

public class Group2
{
    public Name { get; set; }
    public int[] Values;
}
```

I want to convert the Flat array to the `Group1`/`Group2` hierarchy specified above.  The array is as follows:

```
var flats = new []
    {
        new Flat { Group1 = "G1", Group2 = "G1.1", Value = 12 },
        new Flat { Group1 = "G1", Group2 = "G1.1", Value = 22 },
        new Flat { Group1 = "G1", Group2 = "G1.2", Value = 13 },
        new Flat { Group1 = "G2", Group2 = "G1.1", Value = 14 },
        new Flat { Group1 = "G2", Group2 = "G2.2", Value = 15 },
    };
```

So the output will be equivalent to:

```
var result = new []
{
    new Group1 
    { 
        Name = "G1"
        Group2 = [] 
        {
            new Group2 
            { 
                Name = "G1.1" 
                Values = [] { 12, 22 }
            },
            new Group2 
            { 
                Name = "G1.2" 
                Values = [] { 13 }
            },
        }
    },
    new Group1 
    { 
        Name = "G2"
        Group2 = [] 
        {
            new Group2 
            { 
                Name = "G2.1" 
                Values = [] { 14 }
            },
            new Group2 
            { 
                Name = "G2.2" 
                Values = [] { 15 }
            },
        }
    }
}
```

I have tried and failed using `GroupBy`:

```
var result = flats
        .GroupBy(f => f.Group1)
        .Select(f => f.GroupBy(x => x.Group2).Select(y => y.Select(x => x.Value)));
```

I've been fiddling with this in `linqpad` but not found a solution.  I've been trying anonymous types initially but added the group types.

Is this possible with `linq`?

Comment: It's not clear to me what you mean by "the output will be". Are you genuinely wanting just console output, or are you expecting some sort of object structure? If it's the latter, what objects would you want to be where? You've shown the "flat" structure - if you could show the expected result in terms of objects rather than "output" that would make the question more answerable.

Comment: Hey Jon, I've specified the Group hierarchy in the question.  Will redo.

Comment: What have you tried so far ?

Comment: I've been trying to solve using GroupBy but not got anywhere.

Comment: Using extension methods directly is going to make things harder for you. Yes, you can do things that you can't do with LINQ syntax, but starting the "hard way" is a mild form of masochism. Start with LINQ syntax and then change only if you identify something specific that you *need* (e.g. `Select` taking an index).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can perform the following Linq operation :

```
   Group1 [] res = flats.GroupBy( g1 => g1.Group1, 
      (key1,res1) => new Group1{ Group2 = 
         res1.GroupBy( g2 => g2.Group2, 
             (key2,res2) => new Group2{ Values = res2.Select( v => v.Value).ToArray(), 
             Name = key2}).ToArray(), Name = key1}).ToArray();
```

First grouping by the Group1 string, the inner group creates an array of Group2 which is initialised by selecting the integer values & creating an array.

Answer (score 1):

This should do the trick. You want to group the results of a group. So group 2 times.

```cs
var result = flats.GroupBy(x => x.Group1).Select(group1 => new Group1()
{
    Name = group1.Key,
    Group2 = group1.GroupBy(x => x.Group2).Select(group2 => new Group2()
    {
        Name = group2.Key,
        Values = group2.Select(x => x.Value).ToArray()
    }).ToArray()
});
```

Comment: I think you mean group twice.

Answer (score 1):

You just need to use LINQ to build the groupings at two levels:

```
var ans = flats.GroupBy(f => f.Group1)
               .Select(fg => new Group1 {
                                Name = fg.Key,
                                Group2 = fg.GroupBy(f => f.Group2).Select(fg2 => new Group2 {
                                                                            Name = fg2.Key,
                                                                            Values = fg2.Select(f => f.Value).ToArray()
                                                                          })
                                                                   .ToArray()
                       })
               .ToArray();
```

NOTE: In general, it is better to prefer `ToList` instead of `ToArray` unless you have a specific need for the `Array` type (normally interoperability with other code).